# How to get IntRange value from List<Int> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to convert List to IntRange, but I haven't any idea how to do this. Could you help me?

```
val list: List<Int> = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toList()
val rangeFromTheList: IntRange = ??? // 1..5
```

Comment: What if there are gaps in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
fun List<Int>.asRange(): IntRange {
    val range = first()..last()
    if (range.toList() != this) {
        throw IllegalStateException("list is not continuous.")
    }
    return range
}
```

Called like this:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asRange() //OK
listOf(1, 2, 2, 4, 5).asRange() //NOK
listOf(1, 1).asRange() //NOK
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the min and max values from the list and create a range from that:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 3, 5)

val min = list.min() ?: 0
val max = list.max() ?: 0
val rangeFromTheList = min..max
```

Answer (score -1):

Or if it is always in ascending order, simply

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 3, 5)
val rangeFromTheList: IntRange = list.first()..list.last() // 1..5
```